# Running "pod install" in automator action in Mac OS - Permission denied

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, cocoapods, automator

I am currently grading approx 50 apps created by students whereas most of them use CocoaPods in their projects and I'm spending an awful lot of time just navigating in the terminal to different folders just to run "pod install". I googled a bit and found this page:

https://medium.com/@abhishekbedi/podfile-right-click-pod-install-5da88c89c907

Which is exactly what I want, but of course it doesn't work on my computer. I am not proficient in Terminal at all and I can't figure out what I'm missing, any help much appreciated!

Here's what I have in the automator action right now:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
POD="/usr/local/bin/pod"
folder=dirname $file
cd $folder
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 $POD install
```

, which results in the following error:

```
Task ”Run command script” encountered an error: ”-: line 3: /Users/.../Podfile: Permission denied”
```

Maybe I got the text a bit wrong, I just translated it from Swedish.

I've tried chmod on /usr/local/bin/pod and both the file and folders (probably shouldn't have done that), but the error just got worse.

I want all necessary handling inside the script, since any terminal action would defeat the purpose of not having to use the terminal..

Ideas? Thanks